# AssetImage is not switching image accordingly to the screen dimensions

Tags: image, user-interface, flutter, widget, assets

I have images in 6 different dimensions. I'm trying to use the AssetImage to display the right dimensions, but, it uses only the default one.

This is my Pubspec:

```
assets:
    - "assets/"
    - "assets/2.0x/"
    - "assets/3.0x/"
    - "assets/4.0x/"
    - "assets/5.0x/"
    - "assets/6.0x/"
```

In the `assets` folder we find the default images.

Inside the `2.0x, 3.0x` etc. we find the images in different resolutions.

The way I use it:

```
Image.asset("assets/myImg.png"),
```

Comment: what is in `_imagePath`?

Comment: you don't need quotation marks around the paths in the pubspec. https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#declaring-resolution-aware-image-assets

Comment: It doesn't change anything

Comment: have you done a clean installation and rebuild?

Comment: you want specific image on specific condition, related to screen dimension?

Comment: yes, I want to give a specific image on specific condition